# Write to sqlite file from vector of char of pointer in Cocos2dx

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

I am using HttpClient class. When I get the response, I want to write the response data to file. When I check the file, it has wrong format and can't open as a normal sqlite file. What's wrong with my code?

```
 // Get data
    std::string path = cocos2d::FileUtils::getInstance()->getWritablePath()
            + "test.db3";
    auto buffer = response->getResponseData();
    FILE *pFile;
    pFile = fopen(path.c_str(), "wb");
    int size = buffer->size();
    fwrite(&size, sizeof(int), 1, pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
```

Comment: Wel SQLite is a database. So you need to use tables, rows, etc. Just writing out the response to the .db3 file is corrupting it.

Comment: You passed wrong arguments to fwrite. 1st one should be `&buffer` and 3rd is a number of bytes, so you have to count how many are there.

Comment: @GameDeveloper: I need to download SQLite file from server, so I use HttpClient and it returns data = response->getResponseData(). Anyway, I found out the way to solve this problem

Comment: In the future please post your solution as an answer on your own question, and then in two days mark it as accepted. It helps for when someone else runs into this problem and is trying to find an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

```
// Get data
    std::string path = cocos2d::FileUtils::getInstance()->getWritablePath()
            + "serverdb.sqlite";
    auto buffer = response->getResponseData();
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open(path.c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
    ofs.write(&(buffer->front()), buffer->size());
    ofs.flush();
    ofs.close();
```